# Rails: How to use has_many through in multiple degrees of seperation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations

I have a series of model associations using `has_many` / `belongs_to`, as  follows:

`User` < `Company` < `Project` < `Task` > `Employee` > `Company` (circular). As follows:

[image]

I've set up an association between two models with 2 degrees of seperation  (e.g. `Company` and `Task`) by using `has_many :tasks, through: :projects`.

Is it also possible to associate models with multiple (3 or more) degrees of seperation (e.g. `Company` with `Employee`) in such way? Sothat I could perhaps drop the `Company` < `Employee` (hence circular) association.

The goal is to be able to make `employee.company` available, when saving a new employee from my `projects` controller.

Comment: I'm getting confused.

User has_many :companies through: :some_bridge1 //
Company has_many :projects through: :some_bridge2 //
Company has_many :employees through: :some_bridge3 //
Project has_many :tasks through: :some_bridge4 //
Employee has_many :tasks through: :some_bridge5

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Hi @Harfangk, that is indeed what I mean. See my schema above for more clarity. The purpose of my question is to find out if I could drop the `Company` < `Employee` association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

Eg: `Company` with `Employee`

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, through: :projects
  has_many :employees, through: :tasks
end
```

Rails did the magic with `joins` queries

> The goal is to be able to make employee.company available in the Employee model, when saving a new employee from my projects controller.

This is pretty sure, since `Employee` belongs to `Company` already

Comment: @Hieu_Pham. Thanks for your answer, which is very insightful. For clarity, the purpose of my question is to find out if I could drop the `Company` < `Employee` association (otherwise a join association would not be necessary). What you do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that without Company < Employee association to specify which Company hired which Employee.

Granted, even without Company < Employee association, you should still be able to call something like `employee.projects.first.company`. But without direct association, `employee.company` is not possible. You'd always have to specify which Project's Company you're referring to, since Employee has_many Projects. You could add a method to Employee class for shorthand like:

```
def company(project)
    project.company
end
```

and call `employee.company(@project)`. But that doesn't really solve the issue.

Personally, I think it would be more logical to keep that Company < Employee association. The word Employee implies that there's some kind of Employer (could be Company, other Person, self-employed or anything) hiring that Employee.

Comment: Thanks for this insight!